# Trying to get the input data in xml and returns TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, jquery, odoo

please tell me what did I do wrong? But it is successfully created a data in javascript but I always get this error in python:

> > getVals = list([val for val in partner_name[:25] if val.isalnum()]) #limit the domain to 12 chars only
> > TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute `'__getitem__'`

```
def get_db_name(partner_name):
    getVals = list([val for val in partner_name[:25] if val.isalnum()]) #limit the domain to 12 chars only
    result = "".join(getVals).lower()
    if len(result) >= 3:
        return result
    else:
        result = get_random_string(5)
        return result
```

```
$(function()
    {
        $("#start_trial").click(function()
        {
            var db_name = $('input').attr('name', 'partner_name').val();

            session.rpc('/saas/createdb', 
            {
                db_name: db_name,
            }).then(function (result) 
            {
                    console.log('DB name ', db_name)
                    console.log("Database created successfully")
                    $("div.spanner-one").addClass("show");
                    $("div.overlay").addClass("show");
                    $("p.one").addClass("show").fadeOut(5000);      
            });
         }
     });
```

Comment: What parameter are you calling `get_db_name` with?

Comment: Hi @MetallimaX,
This one:


@http.route('/website_form/<string:model_name>', type='http', auth="public", methods=['POST'], website=True)
    def website_form(self, model_name, **kwargs):
        _logger.debug("Custom controller is called!")
        _logger.debug(request.params.get("partner_name"))
        db_name = get_db_name(request.params.get("partner_name"))
        sys_url = get_system_url(db_name, 'custom.com')
        kwargs.update({"website_url": sys_url["url"]})
        res = super(CustomWebsiteFormController, self).website_form(model_name, **kwargs)
        return res

Comment: Please edit your question in order to have correct indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is likely coming from your partner_name variable, so you need to put a check on it:

```
def get_db_name(partner_name):
    result = ''
    if partner_name:
        getVals = list([val for val in partner_name[:25] if val.isalnum()]) #limit the domain to 12 chars only
        result = "".join(getVals).lower()

    if len(result) >= 3:
        return result
    else:
        result = get_random_string(5)
        return result
```

Comment: Hello @SDBot,
When I disabled my js code the python side works. It really get the data of the partner name. I don't know where I am doing it wrong.

Comment: This is in DevTools Console 
`  POST http://localhost:8069/website_form/crm.lead 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)`

Here in my log in eclipse:

  File "~/controller/main.py", line 167, in website_form
    db_name = get_db_name(request.params.get("partner_name"))
  File "~/controller/main.py", line 27, in get_db_name
    getVals = list([val for val in partner_name[:25] if val.isalnum()]) #limit the domain to 12 chars only
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute ```'__getitem__'```

Comment: can you enter to debug mode to see the value of partner_name before error? or print partner_name to console before error.

Comment: it says `None` in console log but in my jscode successfully created a data.
check this img https://jpst.it/2pApW

Comment: ok, did you used the code above? because the "if partner_name:" is to prevent partner_name being None inside the if block

Comment: yes, the error 500 disappeared but still in my python the partner name returns `None` and having a bad query.

Comment: are there new error message? cause after the code above. the error message you posted are impossible to happen

Comment: ah no, there are no errors appeared right now. thank you :)
Now I have to deal with the bad query.
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: i see, you can create new question for the new issue, then post more details about the error